# Moving entire folders with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, directory

This is my very first use of AppleScript. I'm trying to use it to move a 100+ folders (and their content files) from one location to another. I'm not just moving the files because I want to maintain the filing system. So I've got the folders listed in a .txt file in this format:

> Macintosh HD:Users:Tom:Music:iTunes:Afrika Bambaataa
>
> Macintosh HD:Users:Tom:Music:iTunes:Air

And then I run the following in AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set TextFile to (choose file with prompt "Select your text file" of type {"txt"})
    set My_Folder to (choose folder with prompt "Select your destination folder")
    set List_files to paragraphs of (read TextFile)
    move List_files to My_Folder
end tell
```

However the error I receive is the following:

> error "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class." number -10010

Any help on what I'm doing wrong here?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set TextFile to (choose file with prompt "Select your text file" of type {"txt"})
    set My_Folder to (choose folder with prompt "Select your destination folder")
    set List_files to paragraphs of (read TextFile)
    move List_files to My_Folder
end tell
```

Currently, `List_files` is just a list of text objects, i.e.

```
{"Macintosh HD:Users:Tom:Music:iTunes:Afrika Bambaataa",
 "Macintosh HD:Users:Tom:Music:iTunes:Air", ...}
```

so what you're asking *Finder* to do is move some text to a folder, which doesn't make sense.  You need to tell *Finder* that this text represents a path to a folder, by using the `folder` specifier.  Since this can't be done en masse, you have to iterate through the list:

```
repeat with fp in List_files
    move folder fp to My_Folder
end repeat
```

However, I wouldn't actually do it like this, as that will require 100+ separate `move` commands - one for each item in `List_files`.  Instead, we'll edit the list items first by prepending the `folder` specifier to each item, and *then* `move` the list of folders altogether in a single command:

```
repeat with fp in List_files
    set fp's contents to folder fp
end repeat

move List_files to My_Folder
```

Depending how big the files are and how long the transfer will take, the script might time out before the transfer is complete.  I'm not honestly sure what impact this would have on an existing file transfer.  I *suspect* that AppleScript will simply lose its connection with *Finder*, but that the transfer will continue anyway since the command has already been issued (another benefit of using a single `move` command instead of multiples).  But, if you want to avoid finding out, we can extend the timeout duration to be safe:

```
with timeout of 600 seconds -- ten minutes
    move List_files to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:CK:Example:"
end timeout
```

The final script looks something like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set TextFile to (choose file with prompt "Select your text file" of type {"txt"})
    set My_Folder to (choose folder with prompt "Select your destination folder")
    
    set List_files to paragraphs of (read TextFile as «class utf8»)
    
    if the last item of the List_files = "" then set ¬
        List_files to items 1 thru -2 of List_files
    
    repeat with fp in List_files
        set fp's contents to folder fp
    end repeat
    
    move List_files to My_Folder
end tell
```

The extra line that starts `if the last item of...` is just a safety precaution in case the last line of the text file is a blank line, which is often the case.  This checks to see if `List_files` contains an empty string as its last item, and, if so, removes it; leaving it in would throw an error later in the script.

#### EDIT: Dealing with folders that don't exist

If the `repeat` loop throws an error due to an unrecognised folder name, then we can exclude that particular folder from the list.  However, it's easier if we create a new list that contains only the folders that have been verified (i.e. the ones that didn't throw an error):

```
set verified_folders to {}

repeat with fp in List_files
    try     
        set end of verified_folders to folder fp
    end try
end repeat

move the verified_folders to My_folder
```

This also means we can delete the line beginning `if the last item of...`, as the check that this performs is now going to be caught be the `try`...`end try` error-catching block instead.

Comment: Brilliant. This works great. When I generated my test list the encoding creates some flawed folder names where special characters are involved. If I were to add an exception to skip errors and proceed how would I tuck that in?

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it for me. Still gets stuck on Bomba Estéreo. I possibly encoded it in python wrongly. Ultimately I'm not too worried about it though. I did:    np.savetxt(r'remove.txt', remove['Mac_location'].values, fmt='%s', encoding ='utf-8')

Comment: I'm actually more concerned about a tiny side effect. After running it, I can delete the folder to where I've moved the files, but I get an error if I try to change the folder name (An unexpected error occurred (error code -8076).). Deleting the folder works. Odd

Comment: @Kees how did you get on with this ?